# error parsing regexp invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?!`

Tags: regex, re2

I'm validating phone number and email using this regex but I'm getting perl syntax error can anyone help me what to use here

```
^(?:(\d)(?!\1{2}))\d{4,15}$|([A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,3})
```

I'm validating international numbers between 4-15 and also validating continuously repeated numbers like `1111111111111`, `99999999999`, `77777777777` we can't use more than 3 repeated numbers also I'm validating email everything is fine but for the repeated number I've to use Perl syntax ?! that's why I'm getting error please help me to solve this
[image: perl syntax error ss]

Comment: You're not using Perl; you're using something similar to Perl that's not quite compatible. That's what the message is saying. I've replaced the Perl tag with the correct one.

Comment: https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

Comment: @ikegami where you replaced can you show me ?

Comment: You're asking where the tags are located? right below the body of the question

Answer (score 2):

You're not using Perl; you're using RE2. While similar to Perl, it's [not quite compatible](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Specifically, it can't handle the pattern you provided. That's what the message is saying. You'll need to provide something RE2 can handle.

---

The following is the relevant part:

```
^(?:(\d)(?!\1{2}))\d{4,15}$
```

In Perl, that checks for a string of 5-16 digits that's optionally followed by line feed, with the caveat that the first three digits can't be the same.

This is equivalent<sup>[1]</sup> and will work in RE2:

```
^
(?: 0 (?: 0 [1-9]    | [1-9]    [0-9] )
|   1 (?: 1 [02-9]   | [02-9]   [0-9] )
|   2 (?: 2 [0-13-9] | [0-13-9] [0-9] )
|   3 (?: 3 [0-24-9] | [0-24-9] [0-9] )
|   4 (?: 4 [0-35-9] | [0-35-9] [0-9] )
|   5 (?: 5 [0-46-9] | [0-46-9] [0-9] )
|   6 (?: 6 [0-57-9] | [0-57-9] [0-9] )
|   7 (?: 7 [0-68-9] | [0-68-9] [0-9] )
|   8 (?: 8 [0-79]   | [0-79]   [0-9] )
|   9 (?: 9 [0-8]    | [0-8]    [0-9] )
)
[0-9]{2,13}
\n?
\z
```

I don't know RE2, so there might a better solution.

---

1. Assuming `\d` was meant to match `[0-9]`. It actually matches a whole lot more.

Comment: it is not working as well can you validate here https://regex101.com/r/gF6tT0/2

Comment: huh? That's neither the pattern you asked about, nor the one I provided. Also, regex101 doesn't support RE2. In no way does that show that what I posted doesn't work.

Comment: bro checkout this https://regex101.com/r/gF6tT0/2

Comment: Why do you think it's relevant?

Comment: I think regex101 might work if you select golang. At least it doesn't allow negative lookaheads but does allow non-capturing groups.

Comment: @Blaisem fyi, golang wasn't supported by regex101 when the question was asked.